# Unable to make CSS animation centered

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm working on this CSS animation from Animista which is not centered. The entry animation starts and ends not centered and the exit animation starts in the middle and slides down. Which is not how the animation is supposed to work.

The animation is for a popup which gets triggered after a 1-2 seconds and when the user clicks the close button the popup should disappear.

Here's the snipper:

```js
const allEl = document.querySelectorAll('body > *:not(#popup):not(script)');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('#popup-close-btn');
const popup = document.querySelector('#popup');

allEl.forEach(el => {
  el.setAttribute('id', 'blur');
});

const blur = document.querySelector('#blur');

setTimeout(() => {
  blur.classList.add('active');
  popup.style.display = "block";
  popup.classList.add('slide-in-fwd-center');
  popup.classList.remove('slide-out-fwd-center');
}, 2000);

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  blur.classList.toggle('active');
  popup.classList.add('slide-out-fwd-center');
  popup.classList.remove('slide-in-fwd-center');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

#blur.active {
  filter: blur(10px);
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #111;
}

#popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
  padding: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .30);
  width: 600px;
  background: #fff;
  display: none;
}

.slide-in-fwd-center {
  animation: slide-in-fwd-center 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}

@keyframes slide-in-fwd-center {
  0% {
    transform: translateZ(-1400px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateZ(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.slide-out-fwd-center {
  animation: slide-out-fwd-center 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
}

@keyframes slide-out-fwd-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(1);
    transform: translateZ(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(600px);
    transform: translateZ(600px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, harum aspernatur. Hic corrupti inventore voluptatum suscipit soluta sapiente odit delectus, beatae dolor, ea minus nesciunt distinctio dolore nihil itaque odio.
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="popup">
  <h2>Lorem safasfasflijlkasfj oafljka aufhskafkl asoifj </h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit dolore, recusandae enim quisquam nisi, architecto hic sed fugit modi quibusdam odit quia illum ipsa doloremque at reiciendis vitae nam inventore.</p>
  <a href="#" id="popup-close-btn">Close</a>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Very interesting question, hence I upvoted it. Also, please review the edit of my answer. I added CSS that I forgot (zoom out effect, moving popup out of screen at the end) and comment about using **class** `.blur` instead of **id** `#blur`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach to add to answers presented:

The `#popup` element is `position:absolute`, hence to have it **centered** you could take advantage of `calc()` in CSS, as this function allows for mixing of units (like `calc(50% - 300px)`), being the 300px half of your popup's width (600px):

```css
left: calc(50% - 300px);
```

However, then I noticed that for some reason the `translateZ()` would not work as expected.

**Initial thought:**
Should we use `translateZ()` in your case?
Bescause the CSS function `translateZ()` repositions an element along the z-axis in **3D** space, hence it is more appropiate for **3D objects**.
[MDN translateZ()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateZ())

However, here we have a plain **2D** popup. Hence, we could use **2D CSS transform functions** instead.

Following now 2 alternatives for **2D transformations**:

1. **slide-in** / **slide-out**
   `translate(x, y)`
2. **zoom-in** / **zoom-out**
   `scale(x)`

### 2D slide-in / slide-out

Without zoom effect to begin with, replacing `translateZ()` with `translate(x, y)`:

```js
const allEl = document.querySelectorAll('body > *:not(#popup):not(script)');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('#popup-close-btn');
const popup = document.querySelector('#popup');

allEl.forEach(el => {
  el.setAttribute('id', 'blur');
});

const blur = document.querySelector('#blur');

setTimeout(() => {
  blur.classList.add('active');
  popup.style.display = "block";
  popup.classList.add('slide-in-fwd-center');
  popup.classList.remove('slide-out-fwd-center');
}, 2000);

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  blur.classList.toggle('active');
  popup.classList.add('slide-out-fwd-center');
  popup.classList.remove('slide-in-fwd-center');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

#blur.active {
  filter: blur(10px);
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #111;
}

#popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 300px);
  padding: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .30);
  width: 600px;
  background: #fff;
  display: none;
}

.slide-in-fwd-center {
  animation: slide-in-fwd-center 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}

@keyframes slide-in-fwd-center {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-1400px, -1400px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.slide-out-fwd-center {
  animation: slide-out-fwd-center 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
}

@keyframes slide-out-fwd-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1400px, 1400px);
    transform: translate(1400px, 1400px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, harum aspernatur. Hic corrupti inventore voluptatum suscipit soluta sapiente odit delectus, beatae dolor, ea minus nesciunt distinctio dolore nihil itaque odio.
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="popup">
  <h2>Lorem safasfasflijlkasfj oafljka aufhskafkl asoifj </h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit dolore, recusandae enim quisquam nisi, architecto hic sed fugit modi quibusdam odit quia illum ipsa doloremque at reiciendis vitae nam inventore.</p>
  <a href="#" id="popup-close-btn">Close</a>
</div>
```

### 2D zoom-in / zoom-out

Using `scale(x)`:
**Note:**

- 0% to 99%: We **animate the zoom** (`scale()`), and then ...
- 99% to 100%: **move the popup out of screen** (`translate()`)
  (otherwise the content underneath would be covered by our invisible `opacity:0` popup)

```js
const allEl = document.querySelectorAll('body > *:not(#popup):not(script)');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('#popup-close-btn');
const popup = document.querySelector('#popup');

allEl.forEach(el => {
  el.setAttribute('id', 'blur');
});

const blur = document.querySelector('#blur');

setTimeout(() => {
  blur.classList.add('active');
  popup.style.display = "block";
  popup.classList.add('slide-in-fwd-center');
  popup.classList.remove('slide-out-fwd-center');
}, 2000);

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  blur.classList.toggle('active');
  popup.classList.add('slide-out-fwd-center');
  popup.classList.remove('slide-in-fwd-center');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

#blur.active {
  filter: blur(10px);
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #111;
}

#popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 300px);
  padding: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .30);
  width: 600px;
  background: #fff;
  display: none;
}

.slide-in-fwd-center {
  animation: slide-in-fwd-center 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}

@keyframes slide-in-fwd-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(5);
    transform: scale(5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.slide-out-fwd-center {
  animation: slide-out-fwd-center 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
}

@keyframes slide-out-fwd-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(5);
    transform: scale(5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(5);
    transform: scale(5);
    -webkit-transform: translate(1400px, 1400px);
    transform: translate(1400px, 1400px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, harum aspernatur. Hic corrupti inventore voluptatum suscipit soluta sapiente odit delectus, beatae dolor, ea minus nesciunt distinctio dolore nihil itaque odio.
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="popup">
  <h2>Lorem safasfasflijlkasfj oafljka aufhskafkl asoifj </h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit dolore, recusandae enim quisquam nisi, architecto hic sed fugit modi quibusdam odit quia illum ipsa doloremque at reiciendis vitae nam inventore.</p>
  <a href="#" id="popup-close-btn">Close</a>
</div>
```

**Final comment:**
You are assigning an `id` attribute (`#blur`) to acces all direct children elements of the `<body>` for the blur-effect. It is OK in your code snippet that you have presented, because your body has only 1 direct child (parent-child selector `>` , hence `<div class="container" id="blur">`).

But what if we had several direct children elements, like header, content and footer?
Then, our id `#blur` would not be unique anymore within our DOM, as it would repeat multiple times.

You might consider modifying your code by replacing the id `#blur` with a class `.blur`, hence:

CSS:

```css
.blur.active {
  filter: blur(10px);
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

JS:

```js
allEl.forEach(el => {
  el.classList.add('blur');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First problem is your body is loading short. `min-height: 100vh;` solves that.

Second issue is that your animation classes being added are overwriting your default transform property. just have to add X and Y to the animation classes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            position: relative;
            min-height: 100vh;
        }

        #blur.active {
            filter: blur(10px);
            pointer-events: none;
            user-select: none;
        }

        a {
            position: relative;
            padding: 5px 20px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            background: #111;
        }

        #popup {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            padding: 50px;
            box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .30);
            width: 600px;
            background: #fff;
            display: none;
        }

        .slide-in-fwd-center {
            animation: slide-in-fwd-center 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
        }

        @keyframes slide-in-fwd-center {
            0% {
                transform: translateZ(-1400) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
                opacity: 0;
            }
            100% {
                transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }

        .slide-out-fwd-center {
            animation: slide-out-fwd-center 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
        }

        @keyframes slide-out-fwd-center {
            0% {
                -webkit-transform: translateZ(1) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
                transform: translateZ(1) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
                opacity: 1;
            }
            100% {
                -webkit-transform: translateZ(600) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
                transform: translateZ(600) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
                opacity: 0;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <h2>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, harum aspernatur. Hic corrupti inventore voluptatum suscipit soluta sapiente odit delectus, beatae dolor, ea minus nesciunt distinctio dolore nihil itaque odio.
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="popup">
    <h2>Lorem safasfasflijlkasfj oafljka aufhskafkl asoifj </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit dolore, recusandae enim quisquam nisi, architecto hic sed fugit modi quibusdam odit quia illum ipsa doloremque at reiciendis vitae nam inventore.</p>
    <a href="#" id="popup-close-btn">Close</a>
</div>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    const allEl = document.querySelectorAll('body > *:not(#popup):not(script)');
    const closeBtn = document.querySelector('#popup-close-btn');
    const popup = document.querySelector('#popup');

    allEl.forEach(el => {
        el.setAttribute('id', 'blur');
    });

    const blur = document.querySelector('#blur');

    setTimeout(() => {
        blur.classList.add('active');
        popup.style.display = "block";
        popup.classList.add('slide-in-fwd-center');
        popup.classList.remove('slide-out-fwd-center');
    }, 2000);

    closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        blur.classList.toggle('active');
        popup.classList.add('slide-out-fwd-center');
        popup.classList.remove('slide-in-fwd-center');
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And for a most complete answer, for it to slide in like I think you want, set top and left to negative values on 0%, and top:50%, left:50%  on 100% animation. then vice versa on out.